# How to get value from db.any() promise in pg-promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pg-promise

I use pg-promise and i tried to make a request to database in user model to get an array of all users like this:

```
 exports.getAllUsers = function () {
      let users = db.any("SELECT * FROM users;").then(function (data) {
        return data; // in debug mode data is my expected array 
      });
      return users;
    };
```

But when i make get request from controller, it returns promise `Promise { <pending> }`, not an array of json objects that I expected.
There is a controller:

```
exports.getUsers = function (req, res) {
   let users = userModel.getAllUsers();
   console.log(users); // here it outputs Promise { <pending> }
   res.json(users);
 };
```

How to get array instead of promise?

Comment: You are returning the return value of the `then` function call. What do you think that call returns? It returns a `Promise` object.

Comment: @amn Ok, got it. But how to get my desired value? And in debug mode 'data' is an array.

Comment: `data` being array has nothing to do with debug mode, I assure you -- the callback passed to `then` is *always* called with the value of the resolved promise you call `then` on. If the promise returned by `db.any` resolves with an array, then `data` is that array, period. Something else must be at play if you want to assure me it's the debug mode. The type of resolved value can be different depending on whatever, of course -- but that would be internal workings of `pg-promise`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your code. You are exporting a function of your design, `getUsers`, which is supposed to return a sequence of user objects. But it does not -- `db.any(...)` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). How else do you think you can call `then` on the returned object? [`then` is a member function of the `Promise` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), and you pass another function to `then` to work with the actual data (passed as parameter to the function you pass to `then`). Meaning that indeed `data`, as passed to the `then` call invoked on the return value of `db.any(...)` call, is the sequence of users you're after.

The mistake you are making is to assume that if you `return data` from the callback passed to `then`, it will become the return value of the `then(...)` call. It *will not*. `then` *always* returns a `Promise` -- whatever you return from the callback to `then` will become the resolved value of the returned promise, but it is the promise that is returned and that is why your `users` variable is a `Promise`.

You need to read more about promises, and how they are resolved *asynchronously* (*between* running your scripts), and how to synchronise your code on them resolving.

Hint: Use the `await` keyword to wait for and use the value given a promise, like the value you return from the callback that you pass to your `then(...)` call, *or* accept the design of your `getUsers` function returning a promise and adapt the rest of your code to work with that, without use of `await`.

Your `getAllUsers` function can be reduced to:

```js
exports.getAllUsers = function () {
    return db.any("SELECT * FROM users;");
}
```

...and with `await` you can then use it like:

```js
let users = await getUsers();
```

The statement above has to be part of a function that is tagged as `async` though -- ECMAScript requires marking these explicitly in order to allow use of `await` expressions:

```js
async function whatever() {
    let users = await getUsers();
    /// ...
}
```

Execution of a script that invokes an `async` function such as one containing the statement above, will be interrupted by the JavaScript interpreter at each `await` expression, and resumed when the promise expressed after the `await` keyword, resolves to a value, with the value being assigned to the `users` variable.

Using `async` and `await` does require a version of Node.js that can support them, but current release does (as of the time of writing this).

Otherwise you can still keep the `getUsers` function, but you need to use it differently since you can't use `await` -- having to use promises as one did prior to introduction of `await` and `async`, like:

```js
getUsers().then(users => {
    /// Do something with the `users` array.
});
```

At any rate, it looks like you have some holes in your understanding of how promises work, and I recommend you fill these holes by reading about them this time and not just going straight through to the `pg-promise` API, which builds on them.

Comment: Generally, `return await` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I'll elaborate to reduce the function further, eliminating the anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Like you already found out `userModel.getAllUsers()` will return a promise and not an array. You need to wait for this promise to be resolved. This can be done using the an [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).

```
exports.getUsers = async function (req, res) {
   let users = await userModel.getAllUsers();
   console.log(users);
   res.json(users);
};
```

> Note that an `async function` will always return a promise.

Or you can make use of [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method of the returned promise.

```
exports.getUsers = function (req, res) {
   userModel.getAllUsers().then(users => {
     console.log(users);
     res.json(users);
   });
};
```